# Can I use Livedata to create data for a PageKeyedDataSource?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-paging-library

I have a feature that requires paged data. For this I am trying to use the JetPack Paging library.

Ive set up `PageKeyDataSource` and in the examples it shows the async call events which looks quite verbose. Especially if you have to do multiple calls to create the list.

Instead I already have a datasource that makes multiple calls, maps all this and returns a livedata of a page of items.

So I was thinking something like the code below, but I guess it would need to an observer in the DataSource for the list to be passed to the `onResult`

(getsomeCars being the liveData)

```
    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<String>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<String, Cars>) {

        callback.onResult(carsDataService.getSomeCars.value!!,null,"dsd")
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<String>, callback: LoadCallback<String, Cars>) {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<String>, callback: LoadCallback<String, Cars>) {}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a convenience method `observeOnce` to your PagedKeyedDataSource class which listens for the only first update to a `LiveData` object.

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(observer: Observer<T>) {

        observeForever(object : Observer<T> {
            override fun onChanged(t: T?) {
                observer.onChanged(t)
                removeObserver(this)
            }
        })

    }
```

In your app level build.gradle file. Add this

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'
```

Then call the `observeOnce` method on your `LiveData` object, which only observes the first update from your `LiveData` object, then calls callback.onSuccess.

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val observer = Observer<List<Cars>>{
        callback.onResult(it, null, "dsd")
    }
    yourLiveDataObj.observeOnce<List<Cars>>(observer)
}
```

> EDIT

Instead of using LiveData you can interfaces to also achieve the same purpose.
Declare a generic interface

```
interface ApiCallback<T>{

    fun onSuccess(result: T)

    fun onFailure(errMsg:String)

}
```

In your PagedKeyDataSource

```
getSomeCars(object : ApiCallback<List<Cars>>{
            override fun onSuccess(result: List<Cars>) {   
                 callback.onResult(result, null, "dsd")
            }

            override fun onFailure(errMsg: String) {

                Log.w("get some cars failed with err: $errMsg")
            }
        })
```

In `getSomeCars()` function

```
fun getSomeCars(apiCallback:ApiCallback<List<Cars>>){
    //after your multiple api calls call
    apiCallback.onSuccess(carListResults)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wondered about something like that. I was a little nervous if it was ok to Observe it though. I realise this is not a viewModel but I was think it will be referenced in the viewmodel from looking at the tutorial.

And the documentation says ... "However ViewModel objects must never observe changes to lifecycle-aware observables, such as LiveData objects"

Is it still ok to Observe in a Datasource?

Comment: Yes it is ok to observe in a DataSource(but you need to handle removing observers yourself). The keyword from your quote is  "Lifecycle-aware observables". You notice in the answer no LifeCycleOwner was passed to the observer. In this case we handle removing the observers(else you get memory leaks) and this is simplified for your case where you just need to remove the observer after the first update to the LiveData.

Comment: Oh actually the overrides for loadInitial ect are already working on a background thread. So when I try to invoke observeOnce I get...
Cannot invoke observeForever on a background thread

Comment: Sorry about  that . Use kotlin's coroutine to switch observing to the main thread. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Yep that now works. Thankyou. I will use the answer that you've given. But after some thought, I think I might have gone about this the wrong way. Im thinking maybes I should make my PagedKeyedDataSource class more generic, pass the call in that I want to make. I could use this class for other calls that I make to build the list, switchmap over them ect.

Comment: Instead of returning LiveData from your getSomeCars() method. Another better way to achieve what you want is using callbacks (which is more cleaner as compared to the LiveData way). Declare the callback interface, override and pass an instance of your callback and call the corresponding method when everything(your multiple api calls) is successful. I have edited the answer to include the other way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201954/discussion-between-aidanmack-and-networks).

Comment: More issues with this.
on the loadAfter , because we use observe once it appears to only return the same result as found in load initial. Tried ObserveForever which got half way there but im seeing 
callback.onResult already called, cannot call again when onResult is Invoke.
I guess thats to do with ObserveForever being wrapped inside the GlobeScope

Comment: I tried it in both loadInitial() and loadAfter() and it works perfectly. Can you update the question with what you have now.